# Is mathematics the collection of all tautologies?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

What exactly is the definition of mathematics? Some people say it is the study of this or that, but that is simply the study of math, not math itself. I think the definition of math is that it is the collection of all logically true statements, or tautologies. Has any philosopher made this definition before? And is this the true definition of math?

Comment: No, it is not. Tautology is a technical term of propositional logic.

Comment: The theorems of mathematics are not "logically true".

Comment: There are still some logician who think that all of mathematics can be derived from logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logic is usually considered as the collection of all tautologies based on the axioms and inference rules of a certain deductive system, and of course we have a plurality of such systems. Many philosophers thought similarly for math same as your common intuition since most of us just use a common set-theoretic foundational system such as PA or ZFC. Russell is such a philosopher holding similar views regarding math and wrote the famous *Principia Mathematica* with Whitehead to try to subsume math to logic systems completely via his proposed type theory according to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory):

> Between 1902 and 1908 Bertrand Russell proposed various "theories of type" in response to his discovery that Gottlob Frege's version of naive set theory was afflicted with Russell's paradox. By 1908 Russell arrived at a "ramified" theory of types together with an "axiom of reducibility" both of which featured prominently in Whitehead and Russell's Principia Mathematica published between 1910 and 1913. They attempted to resolve Russell's paradox by first creating a hierarchy of types, then assigning each concrete mathematical (and possibly other) entity to a type. Entities of a given type are built exclusively from entities of those types that are lower in their hierarchy, thus preventing an entity from being assigned to itself.

> In the 1920s, Leon Chwistek and Frank P. Ramsey proposed an unramified type theory, now known as the "theory of simple types" or simple type theory, which collapsed the hierarchy of the types in the earlier ramified theory and as such did not require the axiom of reducibility.

Hilbert's formalism is also famous to hold similar views according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)):

> A major figure of formalism was David Hilbert, whose program was intended to be a complete and consistent axiomatization of all of mathematics. Hilbert aimed to show the consistency of mathematical systems from the assumption that the "finitary arithmetic" (a subsystem of the usual arithmetic of the positive integers, chosen to be philosophically uncontroversial) was consistent (i.e. no contradictions can be derived from the system).

> Other formalists, such as Rudolf Carnap, considered mathematics to be the investigation of formal axiom systems.

> Haskell Curry defines mathematics as "the science of formal systems." Curry's formalism is unlike that of term formalists, game formalists, or Hilbert's formalism. For Curry, mathematical formalism is about the formal structure of mathematics and not about a formal system. Stewart Shapiro describes Curry's formalism as starting from the "historical thesis that as a branch of mathematics develops, it becomes more and more rigorous in its methodology, the end-result being the codification of the branch in formal deductive systems."

However, as we all know, later Gödel's incompleteness theorems smashed such naive closed tautologies ideal replacement for math, mathematicians have to constantly create new definitions and deductive systems to resolve new problems here and there, no one closed final system even containing infinite amount of axioms according to some schemas can deductively prove all true propositions there exist in order to solve all problems that can be found based upon Gödel's work, unless we unintelligibly declare *all* true propositions as axioms but we don't explicitly know them all and their consistency cannot be guaranteed either. So in this sense, math is far from being a collection of all conceivable tautologies and some truths of math don't follow merely by its present coined definitions.

Comment: "unless we unintelligibly declare all true propositions as axioms" The other option is to allow infinitary inference rules, like the [ω-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ω-consistent_theory#.CF.89-logic), which says for ex. that if your axioms can prove some mathematical property is true for each individual number, you can turn it into a "for all N" type statement even if that statement isn't provable using finite inference rules. This allows you to prove every statement of true arithmetic from the Peano axioms, see http://m-phi.blogspot.com/2011/03/completeness-of-pa-with-omega-rule.html

Comment: @Hypnosifl thx for your comment and links. ω-consistent systems are a basic requirement for Gödel's incompleteness theorems to apply. A theory consistent in ω-logic (supplied with your mentioned powerful ω-rule) is also ω-consistent. The converse is false, as consistency in ω-logic is a much stronger notion than ω-consistency, and PA with ω-rule becomes complete. Do you know ω-rule is computable? I feel this just shifts our previous inability of proving certain Gödel sentence to some *uncomputable* infinite inference steps, and it may become much worse if applied to real number model of ZFC.

Comment: *Do you know ω-rule is computable?* Isn't it computable in some cases but not others? There should be some propositions of true arithmetic of the "for all N" type that can't be computably proven from the Peano axioms, even though all the corresponding propositions involving specific choices of N are computably provable. Or are you using "computable" to mean something different than a computable proof from the Peano axioms?

Comment: @Hypnosifl my doubt about radical ω-logic (with its ω inference rule) as a kind of new logical foundation of proof theory is similar to quantum logic though originally proposed by JVN and Birkhoff to deal with QM, however, it went out favor quickly and today physicists still apply classic logic to QM successfully even challenged with all its nonclassical results like entanglement...

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the interpretation of Bertrand Russel and the Logicist philosophy of mathematics. (So yes, it has been proposed.) As pointed out in the accepted answer, that whole approach and all its relatives ultimately implode.  But that is not what is important.  You can fail completely at something and still have defined the intention correctly.

This approach via truths and proofs expressed in languages is not a reasonable approach to begin with.  It runs into problems immediately when you look at what mathematicians actually consider important.  (So no, it is not correct.)

On the one hand it is too small: To what degree is geometry reducible to logic? Fine, you can construct the Real Numbers, etc. in Set Theory. But the hard core of 3D Euclidean geometry proceeds pretty obviously from the experience of seeing and moving through our local 3D space, in a way that cannot be explained entirely in language. Its axioms and definitions do not actually capture the subject matter without adding visualizations.

So it seems clear that the core contents of math include instinctual intuitions of various kinds, like our genetic ability to comprehend space, which cannot be reduced to any language, much less that of logic.

At the same time, it is too big: Mathematics does not concern itself with true theorems about bachelorhood and boiling pigs, even though you can state axioms and deduce theorems about those.  It works only from impressions that have less actual content than that, and it leaves it to other sciences to find the content that can be injected to render the theorems meaningful and helpful to the rest of humanity.

What is important to mathematics is remaining abstract, and not getting tied up in references to other parts of reality.  Just because I can reason about something precisely does not render it subject matter for mathematicians.  Even the most rigorous theology is still not math.